# Log Curl Output

Tags: curl

I am trying to log my curl output which looks as following: (which are randomly produced every 10th sec)

```
<RTW>
<RESULT>{ "Result": { "something1": 707,  "something2": { "array": ["95", "51", "65", "33", "95", "109", "87", "37", "49", "86"] } } }</RESULT>
<DISTRICT>{"0000":"City"}</DISTRICT>
</RTW>
```

My command is as following `sh /path/to/script.sh 2>&1 | tee /path/to/logfile.txt`

The issue is that I am not logging the original output I am logging some download statistics (which also shows up in the running terminal window).
The following things are tracked in the download statistics:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   249    0   204  100    45    125     27  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   125
100   249    0   204  100    45     77     17  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    77
```

and so on..

How can I log (what I believe is the stdout) from the curl? I have tried changing the number in the `2>&1` section etc.

My curl command inside the script is as following:
`curl -k --data "objectID=ID&username=username&password=passwd" url -H "Header"`

Comment: You're looking for `-o file.txt`.  You should also consider reading the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `curl` silent, no progress statistics (and error message will be shown), with the `-s` (`--silent`) option:

```
curl -s ...
```

From `man curl`:

> -s, --silent
>
> Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for,
> potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.

Comment: Just tried that, no output data was shown in the file or in the terminal.

Comment: @Chess This is the way to silent `curl`, if no output is being shown you need to look at your script/how you are doing things.

Comment: I will not deny that it is, but it is currently not what I was asking for. But thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

add `| logger` to the end of the curl command.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to get the output of curl is to use the `-s` flag and assign curl's output to a variable.

Using the example you provided, the modification will be like:

```bash
RES="$(curl -k --data "objectID=ID&username=username&password=passwd" url -H "Header")"

#print the result

echo "$RES"
```